# Google Drive thumbnails at different sizes

Tags: google-drive-api

I have noticed that thumbnail URLs generated by Google Drive SDK end in the string "=s220", and if you change this string (eg s500) then you get a different size thumbnail. Is this supported behaviour? If so then it's an incredibly useful feature.

Comment: (I better answer this quickly before people who have no idea about it close the question because they don't understand it)

Answer (score 8):

It is not documented behavior currently (it may be, in the future), but the feature will not be going away soon, and I agree it is very useful.

Comment: Well, for *some* thumbnails the URL seem to have a different format. There it has `&sz=s220`. But this seems all a bit dubious to me. Nothing is documented about this.

Comment: @Ali Afshar: This still doesn't seem to be documented behaviour. It would be really interesting to know about that. In general the Google Drive API documentation seems to be in pretty bad shape - most of the examples don't work any more (PHP SDK), so that in general I dont't feel safe if today's functionality will work the next day / release or if I would have to change lots of code. That's a pity!

Comment: I have few questions. Think Ali is the best person who can answer that.

- Is is documented or not yet? 
- Can I rely on this behavior (different size suffices) in my code?
- Does link to thumbnail long-lived or not?
- Is this thumbnail url public and available for everyone in internet?

Comment: If it's been there from 2012 to 2017, I guess it's "safe" to rely on this, but it would be nice to document it yes :)

Answer (score 1):

s220 is image width in this case. You can change it to any number you want.

Moreover you can remove it and get full size image. It might be useful if you want to show full size image, but do not want to expose file ID or you want to send temporary link to someone. Thumbnail links valid just for limited time. In some projects it might be useful to use thumbnail links for security. Users can not really share links because they will be invalid after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Response from the future to this 8 years old question:

Yes, it is still working today.